# Row wise median for julia dataframes

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I want to compute the median values of all rows in a dataframe. Some columns contain NaN values. Some rows even have all NaN values. The problem with median is

1. if there's any NaN values in a vector it returns NaN. In this case I would like to skip NaNs (like in Pandas).
2. it is undefined for empty vectors (throws an error). In this case I want to return a NaN (like in Pandas)

I came up with the following solution:

> ```
> df = DataFrame(rand(100, 10), :auto) 
> df[1, :x3] = NaN
> df[20, [:x3, :x6]] .= NaN
> df[5, :] .= NaN
>
> safemedian(y) = all(isnan.(y)) ? NaN : median(filter(!isnan, y))
> x = select(df, AsTable(:) => ByRow(safemedian∘collect) => "median")
> ```

This works however it's rather slow.

**Question 1)** Is there a way to speed this up?

I think the collect method is causing the sluggish performance. But I need to use the collect method otherwise I get an error:

> ```
> safemedian(y) = all(isnan.(y)) ? NaN : median(filter(!isnan, y))
> x = select(df, AsTable(:) => ByRow(safemedian) => "median")
>
> # results in ArgumentError: broadcasting over dictionaries and `NamedTuple`s is reserved
> ```

This is because `AsTable(:)` passes each row a named tuple.

**Question 2)** Is there a way to pass rows as vectors instead?

This way I could pass the row to any function that expects a vector (for example the `nanmedian` function from the [NaNStatistics.jl Package](https://brenhinkeller.github.io/NaNStatistics.jl/dev/)). Note I would not need to use the `collect` method if the `AsVector(:)` method was implemented (see [here]). Unfortunately it didn't get the go ahead and I'm not sure what the alternative is.

**Question 3)** This one is more philisophical. Coming from Python/Pandas some operations in Julia are hard to figure out. Pandas for example handles NaNs seemlessly (for better or worse). In Julia I artificially replace the missing values in my dataframe using `mapcols!(x -> coalesce.(x, NaN), df)`. This is because many package functions (and functions I've written) are implemented for `AbstractArray{T} where {T<:Real}` and not `AbstractArray{Union{T, Missing}} where {T<:Real}` (ie. they don't propagate missings). But since there is no `skipnan` yet there is a `skipmissing` function in Julia, I'm thinking I've got it all wrong. Is the idiomatic way to keep missing values in Julia and handle them where appropriate? Or is it ok to use NaN's  (and keep the type fixed as say `Float64`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
filter.(!isnan,eachrow(Matrix(df))) .|>
  v->isempty(v) ? NaN : median(v)
```

Each library has idiosyncracies which melt away with practice. So coming from paNdas you are familiar with pandas and it feels natural. After a while, it is entirely possible you would find things that are natural in Julia to be awkward in panads.

For more perspective, ask this question on Discourse, which has very recently had a thread directly on these issues.

Comment: Thanks - 2x speed up. It would be nice to avoid the matrix contstructor (assuming this will copy data?). I'll ask on discourse too - re general advice.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is probably to redefine `safemedian` to work with `NamedTuple`s (which iterate their values and not their keys).

```
julia> safemedian(y) = all(isnan, y) ? NaN : median((x for x in y if !isnan(x)))
safemedian (generic function with 1 method)

julia> select(df, AsTable(:) => ByRow(safemedian) => "median")
100×1 DataFrame
 Row │ median     
     │ Float64    
─────┼────────────
   1 │   0.326412
   2 │   0.61873
   3 │   0.672079
   4 │   0.405539
   5 │ NaN
   6 │   0.358769
   7 │   0.469862
   8 │   0.585866
  ⋮  │     ⋮
  94 │   0.512761
  95 │   0.43875
  96 │   0.463244
  97 │   0.380401
  98 │   0.45737
  99 │   0.456926
 100 │   0.195296
   85 rows omitted

julia> @benchmark select(df, AsTable(:) => ByRow(safemedian) => "median")
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  63.916 μs …  2.223 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 95.97%
 Time  (median):     65.042 μs              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   68.599 μs ± 79.734 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.30% ±  3.59%

  ▁▅▇██▇▅▄▂▁ ▂▂▃▃▃▃▂▁                                         ▂
  █████████████████████▆▇███▇▇▇▆▅▅▅▆▄▄▅▅▅▁▄▅▄▅▅▅▄▅▅▅▅▁▅▄▃▄▅▃▄ █
  63.9 μs      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      79.1 μs <

 Memory estimate: 62.42 KiB, allocs estimate: 555.
```

Comment: Thanks, certainly an improvement. I would have thought we could have avoided copying whether through collect or list comprehension to apply such a simply vector operation on each row of the DataFrame